# Convert a for loop to linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple for loop but I want to convert it to Linq and return empty Dict. if object is null. I have not used it before. Can anyone help me out on this ?

```
private Dictionary<string, class1> getInfo(IEnumerable<class2> infos)
{
     Dictionary<string, class1> trs = new();
     if (infos is null)
         return trs;

     //This loop I want to convert to linq
     for(class2 info in infos)
     {
        class1 tr = new()
        {
            bi = info.bi,
            state = bi.State,
            res = Enum.value;
        };   
        trs.Add(info.value1, tr);
     }
     return trs;
}
```

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar It is an enum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.ToDictionary()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-todictionary-3(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-1))-system-func((-0-2)))) to create a dictionary from `IEnumerable<class2>`

```
Dictionary<string, class1> trs = infos
     ?.ToDictionary(key => Key.value1, 
                   value => new class1() {
                              bi = value.bi,
                              state = bi.State,
                              res = Enum.value
                            }) ?? new Dictionary<string, class1>();
```

---

**Free Advice** : I highly recommend you to use proper naming conventions while declaring class and variables, this will make your code more readable and easy to understand

Comment: Would it be again x in `x=>new Class1()` and also x in `x=>x.value1` ?

Comment: It is just a predicate, to make it more readable, you can use `key` & `value` as a names. I updated my answer

Comment: So this will be like a for each loop on infos ? And do i need to handle a special case of `infos == null` right ?

Comment: @Newbie you can pick any name instead of x. You define that name before each of the ```=>``` therefore you could have different ones before each of the =>

Comment: Yes it is like a foreach on infos, using linq function. What you want to do if `infos == null`?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar return an empty dict.

Comment: with a question mark like ```infos?.ToDictionary(...); ``` makes a null check before calling ToDictionary

Comment: I understand that it is doing a null check, it will do a loop if only it is not null with "?". But if it is null will it return empty dict. ? i just have this one statement now in my function.